# Incremental Door Pass Riddle - Only Square Positions Open

Tags: python, math

There are hundred doors, all closed to start with, a robot makes 100 passes, such that on every pass it increments by the next starting token. Thus,

```
1, 2, 3,.....
2, 4, 6, 8,....
3, 6, 9, 11,....
4, 8, 12, 16,....
.......
100
```

Every time it visits a door it switches from its current state, thus closes if it was open and opens if it was closed. 
After 100 passes find the number of doors that are open.

The problem is trivial, here's my solution,

```
def door_traversal():
    arr = []
    arr = [0 for i in range(101)]
    for i in range(1, 101, 1):
        for j in range(i, 101, i):
            arr[j] = not arr[j]

    count = 0
    for i in range(1, 101, 1):
        if arr[i] == 1:
            count += 1
    return count
```

The answer is 10 and on checking how do I get this number 10, it seems all the door indices which are perfect square are open.Thus the open doors are

```
1,4,9.....
```

What I've been trying to understand is the math behind, this. Any help with that?

Comment: I don't see how this is programming related. Yes, you have code there, but the actual question is purely mathematical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Factorize the numbers - each factor indicates the 'pass' through which the door is open/closed. Square numbers have odd numbers of factors (9 = 1,3 [twice],9). Everything else has an even number of factors

Comment: Indeed makes sense, so every factor represents which sweep covered that particular door.